pcountOpen() ERROR arguments imply differing number of rows: 102,0
I created an unmarkedFramePCO dataframe to use in pcountOpen() however when I tried to run the pcountOpen model I was met with an error message stating that my arguments imply differing number of rows. I verified that all of my row lengths are in fact the same length.
Code I used to create the detection history matrix
y <- bird[,2:3]
siteCovs <- bird[,c("cotton","corn","soy","rice","woodlot","develop")]
obsCovs <- list(date = bird[ ,7:8],
                year = bird[,5:6])
umf <- unmarkedFramePCO(y = y, 
                           siteCovs = siteCovs, 
                           obsCovs = obsCovs,
                           numPrimary = 4)

Code I used to make the pcountOpen model where I was met with the error message when I tried to run it.
modelbird <- pcountOpen(
  pformula = ~ date + year,  # Detection formula
  lambdaformula = ~ cotton + corn + soy + rice + woodlot + develop,  # Initial abundance formula
  gammaformula = ~ 1,  # Recruitment rate formula
  omegaformula = ~ 1,  # Apparent survival rate formula
  iotaformula = ~ 1,  # Immigration rate formula (if applicable)
  data = umf,  # Data
  K = 110  # Upper index of summation for abundance
)
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 102, 0

I checked the lengths of my rows and they are all the same
Below, example dataset code
> head(bird)
  Nest_BoxID survey1 survey2 average highest point year1 year2 date1 date2     time1     time2 temp1 temp2 wind1 wind2      cotton      corn       soy        rice     woodlot
1     AMKE 1      30      52    41.0      52     2  2022  2022   150   168 0.2965278 0.2743056    22  79.2     3   0.0 0.004317789 0.2043754 0.4945308 0.231145653 0.006044905
2     AMKE A      21      22    21.5      22     1  2022  2022   150   186 0.3125000 0.2972222    25  28.4     3   1.8 0.004960317 0.4419643 0.5163690 0.006448413 0.000000000
3     AMKE C      33      55    44.0      55     2  2022  2022   151   170 0.3312500 0.3159722    26  71.7     5   4.8 0.004295197 0.2342835 0.3326825 0.393205779 0.000000000
4     AMKE 2      38      30    34.0      38     2  2022  2022   151   162 0.2805556 0.2743056    24  74.4     1   0.0 0.001485001 0.1986932 0.6875557 0.058212058 0.000000000
5     AMKE 3      40      18    29.0      40     2  2022  2022   153   160 0.2805556 0.2881944    22  71.5     4   2.2 0.039283651 0.1666667 0.3957250 0.337666089 0.008087811
6     AMKE 4      11       7     9.0      11     2  2022  2022   151   170 0.2930556 0.3430556    23  82.3     2   0.0 0.353552860 0.1545350 0.1577123 0.234257655 0.045927210
     develop
1 0.05497985
2 0.02926587
3 0.03436158
4 0.04752005
5 0.03466205
6 0.04303871


Can you make your code reproducible so that others can try to solve the issue? Specifically, some example data for your object bird is needed. You could, for instance, provide a bit of code that creates an equivalent data frame with random values. Please also check if the example data creates the same error.

I just added some example data!
